# My "SG303" barcode scanner works on Windows. But it doesn't work on Linux; why not?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, dmesg, scanner

I have the following issue with a Barcode Scanner (working fine on PC with Win8.1).
I don't know much about the scanner, it's called "SG303 High Performance CCD Scanner" and I don't know if this one is compatible with Linux.

Using it at a Raspberry Pi B+ (with Raspbian) over USB, the scanner makes the usual "beep" on scanning a barcode, but there is no data transfer (checked this by opening a text file before scanning, there should be the barcode displayed).

Report from the console:

```
$ lsusb | grep Weltrend
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 040b:6510 Weltrend Semiconductor Weltrend Bar Code Reader

$ dmesg
[7510873.817215] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 8 using dwc_otg
[7510873.936455] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=040b, idProduct=6510
[7510873.936498] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[7510873.936518] usb 1-1.3: Product: Bar Code Reader
[7510873.936535] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Weltrend
[7510873.966600] input: Weltrend Bar Code Reader as /devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:040B:6510.0002/input/input1
[7510873.977773] hid-generic 0003:040B:6510.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Weltrend Bar Code Reader] on usb-bcm2708_usb-1.3/input0
```

As far as I get this, the Scanner is used as a keyboard. Is there any driver neccessary?

I don't know the manufacturer of this scanner, so it's hard to find any information about how to "reprogram" it.

**Edit 2015-12-09:**

- I used an active USB-Hub with 5V/1A Output on the Raspberry, the Scanner still didn't work.
- I tried a Ubuntu 15.10 Live-Version on my Laptop, the Scanner runs perfectly fine on this, without installing anything.

Comment: Who bought the scanner?  Where did they buy it from?  Did it include any driver CD or documentation?

Comment: Don't know where it's from, I just have to get this to work ;)
There were no CD/manuals/...

Comment: Where did _you_ get it from? A friend? A co-worker?

Comment: Also, does the barcode scanner work on any desktop Unix? If you don't have a desktop Unix installed, try a Ubuntu or BSD live DVD, or make a live USB stick.

Comment: A friend loaned it out to me, but I don't get it why this matters...
I'll try this with Desktop Linux at the weekend.
Got any other ideas?

Comment: 1.  I saw your recent edit.  OK; I see the scanner works fine with a Ubuntu live CD.  Now, Raspbian is based on Debian.  Does the scanner work with a [Debian live CD](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/)?  Please [edit] your question, then ping me using a comment.  2.  Where did your friend buy the scanner from?